# If Left click ffi in lua

Tags: winapi, lua, ffi, luajit

I'm new to ffi.

Basically I'm trying to get a bool when the mouse left button is clicked.

I've done some research and found something called `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`

However I don't know how to put it in `ffi.cdef` then getting a bool.

Comment: Do you have a window that responds to user input?

Comment: @IInspectable - You can post an answer showing how to create such a window.

Comment: I could (well, I cannot, without reading up on Lua's FFI), but that would be an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program polls the mouse button state once per 1 ms and exits when LMB is pressed

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
ffi.cdef[[
   short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
   void Sleep(int ms);
]]

local function is_key_down(vKey)
   return ffi.C.GetAsyncKeyState(vKey) < 0
end

local function sleep(ms)
   ffi.C.Sleep(ms or 1)
end

local VK_LBUTTON  = 0x01 -- Left mouse button
local VK_RBUTTON  = 0x02 -- Right mouse button
local VK_MBUTTON  = 0x04 -- Middle mouse button
local VK_XBUTTON1 = 0x05 -- X1 mouse button (Back)
local VK_XBUTTON2 = 0x06 -- X2 mouse button (Forward)

sleep(1000)
print"Waiting for Left Mouse Button pressed"
repeat
   sleep()
until is_key_down(VK_LBUTTON)
print"Left Mouse Button is down now"
```

If you want to handle WM_LBUTTONDOWN message that would be a more complex solution.

Comment: Unless `sleep()` is implemented as a busy wait, there is no reason to assume that the code were to poll once every 1ms. And if it is indeed using a busy loop, there's no practical reason to even call it.

Comment: @IInspectable - Yes, time intervals in `sleep()` below one timeslice are implementation-dependent.  But for a human-controllable mouse everything below 20ms would be just fine.

Comment: Humans aren't the only source of input events. There's `SendInput`, after all, and this proposed solution is likely to miss those events.

Comment: @IInspectable - You probably will be banned on any game server for generating `SendInput` faster than a human can press mouse buttons :-)

Comment: I doubt that you get banned from a game server for interacting with buttons using a touch screen. Besides, games aren't the only type of program to accept input. There is nothing game specific in the question.

Comment: What else we might need Windows for in 2021, except games? :-)

Comment: The same thing we needed Windows for in the past: An OS with a stable API, and a well designed kernel. There's little competition in either department. None of that makes the issues with this proposed answer go away.